# Convert PDF to PNG - Java 10 gives a different result than Java 8

Tags: java, pdf, png, pdfbox

I want to convert PDF to PNG file.
But for some reasons, Java 10 gives a different PNG than Java 8

```
private static void writeImageToPath(String sourcePath, String path, int pageWidth, int pageHeight) throws IOException 
{

    File sourceFile = new File(sourcePath);
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceFile);
    PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    BufferedImage buff= renderer.renderImage(0, 1, ImageType.ARGB);
    File outputfile = new File(path);
    Image image = buff.getScaledInstance(pageWidth, pageHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(pageWidth, pageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", outputfile);
}
```

I read that the compression settings have changed in Java 9 PNG writer, so that might be why I'm seeing different results from Java 8. https://github.com/gredler/jdk9-png-writer-backport

Do you know how can I overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In what ways is it different?

Comment: I want to check the pixels of the PNG and see which of them have transparency... and Java 10 gives a different result than Java 8.. I use: 
Color pixelColor = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j), true);
int a = pixelColor.getAlpha();
boolean coloredPixel = (a != 0);

Comment: Please share your PDF file. Slight differences are always possible. Especially if you were using KCMS with jdk8, which no longer exists in jdk10. I'm also wondering why you convert your image instead of saving `buff` directly. That makes your question more complex.

Comment: I appreciate your help!! 

You can download the files from:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b550fd4942c32d8556f098a1ecae2fe120181107075004/c11717

Comment: I didn't understand your suggestion regrading "convert your image instead of saving buff directly" .. all I want is to get the same PNG from Java 8 and Java 10..

Comment: You are copying `buff` to `bufferedImage` and then save. Why don't you save `buff` directly? I haven't looked at your file yet, but I can tell you that you won't get absolutely identical PNG files between java versions. There can always be small differences.

Comment: OK I saw it... yes there are some tiny differences. So what? Your PDF files contains curves. It is quite possible that the algorithm was changed between versions. I have run pixel diff tests on PDFBox for years (to detect regressions), and I'm used to small differences. See TestPDFToImage.java in the source code... pixel difference values up to 3 are ignored.

Comment: thank you! my problem is that I need to get the smallest circle of a content in the PNG (that's why I check the pixels of the PNG and see which of them have transparency), and this tiny differences change the circle which cause to a different output. and the output have to be the same between java version... do you have any idea how can I get it?  much appreciate your help :)

Comment: No I don't. I wish I had because it would save time. The differences make regression tests difficult. When I test PDFBox with a new java version (to see if there is anything needing attention), I do a visual inspection of the visual diff files. This takes a lot of my time.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help!!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: accept it.

There are often slight differences in the rendering between jdk versions. For jdk8, the use of the Kodak CMS color management system is recommended (see [Getting started](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/getting-started.html)) because the new LittleCMS was very slow, and Kodak CMS is no longer available in jdk10, so now Little CMS is used. The rendering result has slightly different (usually better) colors. Curve drawing may also be slightly different.

I have run pixel diff tests on PDFBox for years (to detect regressions), and I'm used to small differences. See TestPDFToImage.java in the source code... pixel difference values up to 3 are ignored.

Even with that, there are still slight differences, which make regression tests difficult. When I test PDFBox with a new java version (to see if there is anything needing attention), I do a visual inspection of the visual differences files. This takes a lot of time (these tests are done on over 1000 PDF files).

There are also visual differences between different OS, or even different computers with the same OS, because of different fonts installed.

Comment: Ok,  Thank you!!

Comment: @TilmanHausherr What lib/code do you use for your comparison of the images? Or did you write it yourself? (Or is it even part of pdfbox?)

Comment: It is in TestPDFToImage.java in the test segment of the core project. I wrote parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

That was part of the reason why I switched to [pngj](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj). Since that lib is stable (unless I do upgrade or change something) I get stable results. And it is ~100% faster than the old PNGWriter and still ~20% faster than the backported version of the PNGWriter. I already talked to tilman to add this code to pdfbox but I didn't have the time to do it yet.

Interestingly I disovered the problem with the imageIO PNGWriter myself and thought about patching it but then saw your link to the backported version and the integration in java9. So somebody else was faster :-)

Comment: I doubt the differences are related to PNG encoding.

Comment: I can't remember that we talked about it (or forgot it, LOL). First thing to check is whether the license is compatible.

Comment: We did talk by mail on 17.10 :-)